# How to set data for a specific column using jQuery DataTables table plugin in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm new with jQuery DataTables plugin.  I have encountered an issue which I'm stuck and don't have an idea on how to proceed.

First, this is the implementation inside of my controller class (PlaylistId is of type GUID)

```
    public ActionResult PlayListAjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
            var result = from c in playLists
                         select new IComparable[]
                         {
                             c.PlaylistName,
                             c.PageSecondsRefresh,
                             c.ImageSecondsRefresh,
                             c.SubscriptionName,
                             Convert.ToString(c.PlaylistId)
                         };

            return Json(new
            {
                param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = playListViewModel.Count,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = files.Length,
                aaData = result
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is the structure of JSON data that is returned

```
{
"sEcho": "1",
"iTotalRecords": 3,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
"aaData": [
    ["ChorusLab", 86400, 3, "Solta", "4020b281-2af6-478e-a9a2-b3582d5941db"],
    ["Solta Landscape", 60, 2, "Solta", "3fd61499-fa1e-4584-bcad-57cdd40d2b4b"],
    ["Solta Portrait", 0, 0, "Solta", "1b08e36a-dbe4-4846-a91e-24ec69453407"]
]
```

}

As you can see, aaData is an array of element 3 which each element is also an array. I want to bind the GUID element inside of this array to an anchor tag in my page.

script implementation in .cshtml page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $("#tblPlaylist").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Content("PlayListAjaxHandler")",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "sName": "PlayListName",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "sWidth": '30%'
            },
            {
                "sName": "PageRef",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "sWidth": '10%'
            },
            {
                "sName": "NextImg",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "sWidth": '10%'
            },
            {
                "sName": "Subscription",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "sWidth": '20%'
            },
            {
                "sName": "Action",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "sWidth": '30%',
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a href=\"PlayListEdit/' + data[4] + '\">Edit</a><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' +
                           '<a href=\"ViewContent/' + data[4] + '\">View Files</a><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' +
                           '<a href=\"Play/' + data[4] + '\">Play</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

My problem is, I'm not sure if that is the correct way to bind the returned data (specifically the PlaylistId) into the 3 anchor tags (Edit, View Files, Play).

```
{
                "sName": "Action",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "sWidth": '30%',
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a href=\"PlayListEdit/' + data[4] + '\">Edit</a><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' +
                           '<a href=\"ViewContent/' + data[4] + '\">View Files</a><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' +
                           '<a href=\"Play/' + data[4] + '\">Play</a>';
                }
            }
```

I have checked the documentation in [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data/) but I can't get the correct way of doing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its good place to do it. but to use data[4] you must add to parameters of render function function ( data, type, full, meta ) and use I think full[4] etc.

Comment: @rad11 why I haven't seen that in the documentation.  Maybe, I didn't look hard at all.  By putting this line 'function(data, type, full, meta)' in my render function and use full parameter, the PlaylistId GUID is now bind to the three anchor tags.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @rad11 thanks for you answer, I really appreciate it.  I have another question related with DataTable which I posted in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380714/how-to-invoke-ajax-call-in-jquery-datatable-using-asp-net-mvc.  Maybe you have already encountered this one? any idea is greatly appreciated